# Redbean Updating Linking Values For Shared Lists

Tags: redbean

I have two tables linked together: product and attributetype linked through attributetype_product.  The linking table has some data about the relationship in it. I cannot figure out an easy way to update the data in that linking table using Redbean.  Setting the initial data is easy enough using the link() function.  However I cannot figure out how to change that relationship easily.  I know I can use ownAttributetype_product to update that record once I've loaded the product bean, but that requires that I know the ID of the linking record.

Any help on how to update the link, potentially through the shared list?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to make this work is to load the linked bean then iterate over it's sharedAttributeTypeList until I get to one that has the right primary bean id.

```
$project = R::dispense( 'project' );
$project->name = 'useless';
$employee = R::dispense( 'employee' );
$employee->name = 'employee';
$project->link('employee_project', [ 'role' => 'director' ])->employee;
R::store( $project );

$directors = $project
  ->with(' employee_project.role=?', [ 'director' ] )
  ->ownEmployeeList;
$director = reset( $director );
foreach( $director->xownEmployeeProjectList as $bean ){
  if( $bean->project_id == $project->id )
    break;
}

//now $bean contains the correct Employee_Project bean and can be worked on
```

Most often, however, slight design and scope changes in how I was accessing and thinking about linking beans made this type of access unnecessary. It really does help to look at why you are adding qualifications to a linking bean and then try to abstract that into its own domain model or to limit the scope of access allowed that would require this kind of looking through linking beans so that you can already know, in my example, the project id, employee id or other information that will specify which linking bean you need and then just use the "with" to retrieve only the necessary linking bean.